# Can you still make a custom villager that sells custom potions? Java 1.16.2

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to figure out if you can still create custom villagers that sell custom potions such as speed 10.

```
/summon villager ~ ~1 ~ {Offers:{Recipes:[{buy:{id:acacia_planks,Count:1},sell:{id:potion,Count:1,tag:{Potion:"minecraft:water",CustomPotionEffect:[{Id:3,Amplifier:2,Duration:180}]}}}]}}
```

The villager spawns however, the trade is just a water bottle with no potion effect.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I updated my post to include the command I'm working with.

Comment: So, what's wrong with that command? Does the villager fail to summon? Does the vilager have default trades? Does the sold potion not have any effects? Something else?

Comment: The villager spawns however, the trade is just a water bottle with no potion effect.

Comment: Please only include the bare basics needed to reproduce your problem. For example, the `VillagerData` tag has nothing to do with the fact potions are not working. Next time, please be sure to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I've edited your command so that it is the bare basics of what is needed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

`CustomPotionEffect` is not a valid NBT tag. The correct name is `CustomPotionEffects`.

Fixed command:

```
/summon villager ~ ~ ~ {Offers: {Recipes: [{buyB: {id: "minecraft:air", Count: 0b}, buy: {id: "minecraft:acacia_planks", Count: 1b}, sell: {id: "minecraft:potion", Count: 1b, tag: {Potion: "minecraft:water", CustomPotionEffects: [{Duration: 180, Id: 3b, Amplifier: 2b}]}}}]},VillagerData:{profession:"minecraft:farmer",level:1}}
```

You must provide a villager profession to be able to trade with the villager.

Comment: Wait... If the `buy` tag is like that, then would it be possible for both `buy` items be air or `Count` be 0, making it free?

Comment: So if we set the price to **0**, what would happen?

Comment: So that would still make the trade impossible.